# How to simulate network issues such as packet loss, delay when streaming audio?

Tags: networking, video-streaming, audio-streaming

I have audio files and I want to apply some network issues on it such as packet loos, jitter, delay..
I need emulator to apply this network conditions on my audio file.. please  what is best and appropriate emulator for my work and can install it on windows...

Comment: Questions asking for tools recommendations are off-topic on StackOverflow. Maybe take a look at https://medium.com/docler-engineering/network-issues-simulation-how-to-test-against-bad-network-conditions-b28f651d8a96.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are looking on how to achieve this, as the title suggest and do not want to start an emulator/simulator hate-war here. I suggest you take a look at [mininet](https://github.com/mininet/mininet).

It has got a command line interface for simple tasks and a python API that will let you customise most aspects of the network (such as bandwidth capacity, latency, loss rate etc).
All you need to do is setup two (or more) hosts, connect them with a link and configure the link properties. This is an easy way to get varying latency as you requested. Additionally, you can set a link-loss percentage 0-100%. But if you are looking into dropping a specific packet you will either have to do that at the hosts themselves with help of the transport protocol, or create a custom controller (switch implementation).

Here is a snippet using the python API that might get you started:

```py
from mininet.topo import Topo
from mininet.net import Mininet
from mininet.node import CPULimitedHost
from mininet.link import TCLink
from mininet.util import irange

class MySingleSwitchTopo( Topo ):
    "Single switch connected to k hosts."

    def build( self, k=2, **_opts ):
        "k: number of hosts"
        self.k = k
        switch = self.addSwitch( 's1' )
        for h in irange( 1, k ):
            host = self.addHost( 'h%s' % h )
            self.addLink( host, switch, loss=0.1, latency=20, bw=5 ) # create a link with 20ms latency, 0.1% loss chance and 5Mb bandwidth capacity

if __name__ == '__main__':
    topo = MySingleSwitchTopo()

    net = Mininet(topo=topo, host=CPULimitedHost, link=TCLink)

    net.start()

    h1, h2 = net.get('h1', 'h2')

    h1.cmd('iperf -s&') # Replace with your audio server app
    out = h2.cmd('iperf -c ' + h1.IP()) # Replace with your audio client app

    print(out) # output from the client app

    net.stop()
```